# How to delete contacts from sim in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

I did following code for deleting selected contacts from sim card. but its not deleting and also not throwing any error.

```
protected void DeleteContacts(ArrayList<String> ids){

        int flg = 0;

        String[] strids = new String[ids.size()];
        strids = ids.toArray(strids);

        for (int i = 0; i < strids.length; i++) {

            Cursor sims = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"), null,
                    "_id=?", new String[]{strids[i]}, null);

            sims.moveToFirst();
            if (sims.getCount()>0) {
                String phoneNumber = sims.getString(sims.getColumnIndex("number"));
                boolean val = deleteContact(phoneNumber);
                if (!val)
                    flg=1;
            }

            if (flg == 0)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contact Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sims.close();
        }
    }

    public boolean deleteContact(String phone) {
        Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"), null, "number=?", new String[] { phone }, null);
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    return true;
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You are getting sim's contacts in cursor? If not [check this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html)

Comment: yes, in cursor sims..

Comment: @MysticMagic i done with getting sim contacts.. problem is, how to delete..

Comment: Okay. Have you added permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />?

Comment: yes, i added that also..

Comment: Ok cross check with code in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10058793/1777090) answer then.

Comment: that same code i am using except URI for sim contacts..

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting the contacts from the sqlite database and not the SIM card. For deleting contacts from the SIM card, you need to delete on Uri.parse("content://icc/adn") uri only. But for deletion you need to provide both name and number. Name column has to specified as tag. Check for delete method here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/9ebea45a36838f0547a9c30f7cd9c60b03aab3b4/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccProvider.java

Answer (score 1):

Based on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844393/2003986), here is the solution :

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/");
ContentResolver mContentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
Cursor c = mContentResolver.query(simUri, null, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
        if (/* your condition here */)
        {
            mContentResolver.delete(
                simUri,
                "tag='" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) +
                "' AND " +
                "number='" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")) + "'"
                , null);
            break;
        }                       
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Off course, don't forget these permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```