# How to delete sim card contact in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, sim-card

below is my code for delete contact from phone

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(phone));
        Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null,
                null, null, null);
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    if (cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME))
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                        String lookupKey = cur
                                .getString(cur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,
                                lookupKey);
                        mContext.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                        flag=true;
                        break;
                    }

                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            flag=false;
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
```

delete contact from phone is working fine but sim  contact delete temporary mean when my phone is restart my contact is recover that i deleted.
help in find solution for this problem.
Thanks...

Comment: Check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26971638/2058260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI you want to use is this one : `content://icc/adn/`

Moreover, you have to use the `name` and the `number` to delete a contact.

Try something like this (works for me) :

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/");
ContentResolver mContentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
Cursor c = mContentResolver.query(simUri, null, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
        if (/* your condition here */)
        {
            mContentResolver.delete(
                simUri,
                "tag='" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) +
                "' AND " +
                "number='" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")) + "'"
                , null);
            break;
        }                       
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Off course, don't forget these permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i am read both phone and sim at same time how can i identify contact from sim or phone.

Comment: They are in two different places, identified by two different Uri. Each contact comes from on or the other place. What is the issue ?

Comment: ok, i understand your point but what happen when i have dual sin device, current using this uri i read only my master sim contact

Comment: Good question. I guess its all about which sim is currently activated. I don't think both sim can be read at the same time, but i could be wrong.