# how can i delete a contact after choosing it in my intent android

Tags: java, android

How can I delete a contact after choosing it in my intent android?
 I tried searching but I couldn't find anything, thanks in advance!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) !=null)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==1  && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a contact programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527216/how-to-remove-a-contact-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **ContentResolver** & **Cursor Query** to delete particular contact.Below Usage :

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, null);
 try
    {
     cr.delete(contactUri, null, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work my app crashes after I chose a contact and it didn't delete it.

Comment: can you please send me your crash log